# Java runtime cast to generic interface without losing type information

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have a generic interface that can be implemented by different subclasses of an abstract base class.

```
interface PropertyOne<T> {
  T type();
  List<String> values();
}
```

In the base class I defined a small helper method that checks if the current instance implements that interface and cast to it if possible:

```
<T> Optional<T> toProperty(Class<T> clazz){
    if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(this.getClass())){
      return Optional.of(clazz.cast(this));
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

I use this helper method for example to get and print those values:

```
void printValues() {
    List<String> values = toProperty(PropertyOne.class)
      .map(p -> p.values())
      .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
    System.out.println(values);
}
```

But this gives me a unsafe cast warning, since `values()` now returns a `List` instead of a `List<String>`. I know that the generic type information is lost after compiling the code, but since the return type of `values` is always a `List` of type `String` it should be safe anyway?

Using the following boilerplate code works without warnings.

```
if ( this instanceof PropertyOne<?>){
   List<String> vs = ((PropertyOne<?>)this).values();
   System.out.println(vs);
}
```

I can do a manual cast for the first variant as well like `.map(p -> ((PropertyOne<?>)p).values())` to get rid of the warning but this again adds a lot of boilerplate.

So I got two questions:

1. Why is the `List<String>` type information lost in the first place?
2. Is it possible to dynamically cast to a wildcard/ unbounded type directly without manually doing a cast to `PropertyOne<?>` afterwards?

Comment: Took me a while to figure out, but: any raw type erases _all_ types, and you have a raw type when you specify `PropertyOne.class`, because it isn't a `PropertyOne<Something>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the generics on `Class<T>` are quite limited and cannot be used in this fashion (I'd say the generics on `j.l.Class` are broken, but that's perhaps a bit harsh. They also have some use, just.. not much). Generics can represent things that a class instance cannot; class instances (an instance of `java.lang.Class` can represent things that generics cannot. Specifically, `List<String>` cannot be expressed as a class instance, and `int.class` is a class instance that cannot be expressed in generics.

In other words, the moment you try to communicate a full generified type (such as `PropertyOne<String>`) in a `java.lang.Class<T>` instance, you lost the game - that T in `j.l.Class` can only ever be a generics-less type.

So, this is not how to do it.

your `toProperty` method has got to go. Not for the issues in this post; it's about trying to invoke `type()` on your PropertyOne instance derived from the (optional-wrapped) toProperty call.

Separate from that, the reason that you're running into trouble on your `values()` invocation, which seems to have no actual relevant generics parts to it, is because of archaic java rules: Once you go 'raw', *EVERYTHING* is raw, even the things that don't need it.

So, in `toProperty(PropertyOne.class)`, that would end up returning an `Optional<PropertyOne>` - a raw type, because that's not okay; you'd need e.g. `PropertyOne<?>` which is different from `PropertyOne` (that last one is raw; the former is not) - but you can't do that with `Class<T>`, because `Class<T>` is broken. Now you're in raw territory, and invoking `values()` on this raw type will end up returning a raw list (just `List`), you'd think that still gives you a `List<String>` as the return type of `values()` is not dependent on the generics of `PropertyOne` but that's just not how it works, java lang spec says no.

There are a few ways out of this conundrum, but mostly you're just misusing generics here, you can't really do any of this. Remember, generics are a figment of the compiler's imagination: They do not exist at runtime whatsoever. There's no way to runtime check anything. Once you start mixing generics and runtime constructs such as `instanceof` or `x.isAssignableFrom`, it's never going to work out.

If you must, you may get there with something called 'Super Type Tokens' - you can google for that (toss in 'java' as a keyword), these CAN represent quite precisely anything you can stick inside generics. But that still sounds like a mistake; but I can't really tell you what you have to do here, your problem description is talking about a broken solution and not about the problem that your broken solution is trying to solve.

Comment: Too bad... I hoped that I've maybe missed a minor tweak here to at least cast to a raw type. Something like passing PropertyOne<?>.class. The Java type system, especially generics is realy limitted. I tried to shorten my implementation for the sake of demonstration. In the real "solution" I got in fact a wierd predefined type hierachie which I try to compensate with something like mixins to reduce a lot of duplicate code.